# Undefined value in Javascript loop

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript loop, that loops through a DOM objectes in a table.

However when the loop gets to an undefined cell value, it throws an error.

TypeError: table.rows[i].cells[1] is undefined

I have tried to use an if statement to catch the undefined values, but that has not fixed the issue.

Here is my code:

```
var table = win.document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    //iterate through rows

    if (typeof table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML === 'undefined')
    {
        //Do nothing!
    }
    else
    {
        alert(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
    }


    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        //iterate through columns
        //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `table.rows[i].cells[1]` that is `undefined`, not `table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks, I just realised the same and posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else.

It is not he innerHTML that was undefined, but the table.rows[i].cells[1]

If I update my code as per the below, the issue is resolved

```
var table = win.document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    //iterate through rows
        alert(typeof table.rows[i].cells[1] !== 'undefined' ? : table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML : 'undefined');

    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        //iterate through columns
        //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
    }
}
```